# telethon: how to use bot to send message to a private channel

Tags: python, telethon

I am trying to use my bot to send messages to a private channel, but for some reason it always treat my channel name `My_channel` as a peer user

```py
class Telegram(object):
    """Telegram Class"""

    def __init__(self, name: str, api_id: int, api_hash: str, config_path: str, bot_token=''):
        self.name = name
        self.session = os.path.join(config_path, f'{self.name}.session')
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.bot_token = bot_token if bot_token else None
        logging.info(f"Telegram: Start session: {self.name}")
        self.client = TelegramClient(self.session, self.api_id, self.api_hash)
        self.client.start(bot_token=self.bot_token)

    def send_message(self, receiver, message, mark_as_read=False):
        """Send telegram message

        Args:
            receiver (str): the reciever's accout, i.e. @someone
            message (str): The message to send
            mark_as_read (bool, optional): If mark reciever's message as read. Defaults to False.
        """
        logging.info(f"""Telegram: Sending "{message}" to {receiver}.""")
        self.client.send_message(entity = receiver, message = message)
        if mark_as_read:
            logging.info(f"Telegram: Mark {receiver}'s message as read.")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.client.send_read_acknowledge(receiver)

    def get_joined_channel(self):
        for dialog in self.client.iter_dialogs():
            channelId = dialog.entity.id
            channelName = dialog.name

    def disconnect(self):
        logging.info(f"Disconnect session: {self.name}")
        self.client.disconnect()

tg = Telegram(profile["name"], profile["api_id"], profile["api_hash"], config["config_dir"], profile.get("bot_token"))
tg.send_message(message["receiver"], message["message"])
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/telegram_send_msg.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/telegram_send_msg.py", line 81, in main
    tg.send_message(message["receiver"], message["message"], mark_as_read=profile["name"] == "duchenpaul")
  File "/app/telegram_send_msg.py", line 56, in send_message
    self.client.send_message(entity = receiver, message = message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/messages.py", line 838, in send_message
    entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 461, in get_input_entity
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=1909685838) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.
```

I think the problem is the session cache does not record any information about the channel, and for bot user, telegram does not allow me to use `iter_dialogs`, so how to fix that?

Comment: this is expected. you must receive an event related to this private channel to cache it in the .session file, id cannot be used alone unless with the stored `access_hash`. and prepend -100 to the id to declare it's a channel id: `-1001909685838`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by replacing the channel name/group name with ID, it is not the best solution, but it works.